# Queuing system for actionscript

Tags: serialization, actionscript, queue, eval

Is there an actionscript library providing a queuing system?
This system would have to allow me to pass the object, the function I want to invoke on it and  the arguments, something like:

```
Queue.push(Object, function_to_invoke, array_of_arguments)
```

Alternatively, is it possible to (de-)serialize a function call? How would I evaluate the 'function_to_invoke' with the given arguments?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific queue or stack type data structure available in ActionScript 3.0 but you may be able to find a library ([CasaLib](http://casalib.org/) perhaps) that provides something along those lines.

The following snippet should work for you but you should be aware that since it references the function name by string, you won't get any helpful compiler errors if the reference is incorrect.

The example makes use of the [`rest` parameter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html) which allows you to specify an array of arbitrary length as the arguments for your method.

```
function test(... args):void 
{
    trace(args);
}

var queue:Array = [];
queue.push({target: this, func: "test", args: [1, 2, "hello world"] });
queue.push({target: this, func: "test", args: ["apple", "pear", "hello world"] });

for (var i:int = 0; i < queue.length; i ++) 
{
    var queued:Object = queue[i];
    queued.target[queued.func].apply(null, queued.args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that works similar to JavaScript

```
const name:String = 'addChild'
    , container:Sprite = new Sprite()
    , method:Function = container.hasOwnProperty(name) ? container[name] : null
    , child:Sprite = new Sprite();
if (method)
  method.apply(this, [child]);
```

So a query method could look like:

```
function queryFor(name:String, scope:*, args:Array = null):void
{
    const method:Function = scope && name && scope.hasOwnProperty(name) ? scope[name] : null
    if (method)
        method.apply(this, args);
}
```